# UIView: touches: swiping?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there any easier way of detecting a swipe motion and its direction without doing touchesBegin and touchesEnd?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`? You create the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and then add it to your view check out the docs [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Setting it up may look like this:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiped:)];
[myView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
[swipeRecognizer release]; swipeRecognizer = nil;
```

Then implement your method that will be called when swiped (this is the `@selector(swiped:)`)

```
- (void)swiped:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGestureRecognizer
{
    if (swipeGestureRecognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        NSLog(@"Direction = right");
    } else if (swipeGestureRecognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Direction = left");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working only one direction. You should use like this for 2 direction.

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizerLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiped:)];
swipeRecognizerLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[_cameraView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizerLeft];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizerRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiped:)];
swipeRecognizerRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[_cameraView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizerRight];
```